# Make Multiple Directories in Windows From Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to change the following batch file to use spaces instead of underscores. However, when I do that the directories come out weird. I've tried using quotation marks, but they come out wrong.

```
md Sample_sample
md Sample_sample\sample
md Sample_sample\sample2
md Sample_sample3
md Sample_sample2
md Sample_sample\sample\sample
```

PS. This is for the purposes of building a folder structure in GroupWise in a proxy folder so files can be archived from multiple accounts. If anybody know's how to make a large number of folders as above in GroupWise 7.0 on a proxy account and in a corporate security environment please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Using double quotes works fine. Tested on Windows 7:

```
md "Special Dietary Foods\Infant Formula and Food"
```

Comment: Do they have to be smart quotes?

Comment: @Liam I don't know what you mean? Normal double ones `"` should do

Comment: @Liam I don't understand... copy+paste them from my answer, those will work